# writing to a sound file in netlogo : or how to tune netlogo

Tags: wav, netlogo, synthesizer

I am writing a simple synthesiser.

This is the totality of my code

```
turtles-own [f]
  to setup
    ca
    file-close
    file-open "tune.snd"
    crt 1 [set f 100]
    reset-ticks
 end

to go
   file-write mean [sin(2 * pi * f * ticks)] of turtles
   tick
 end
```

when I run

```
Repeat 44100 [go] file-close
```

and load the output into a sound editor at 44100 hertz I get one second of sound. All is good so far. Unfortunately, it is meant to be a 100 Hz tone but instead, it is one second of something quite a bit higher [over 16k Hz].

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what sound editor takes a list of numbers like that as a sound file?

Comment: goldwave takes a lot of exotic formats including a comma delimited list of floating points. They call it ASCII precise mono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, this is awesome!

The problem's simple. `sin` in NetLogo uses degrees, not radians.

Comment: sin(2 * pi * f * ticks * 0.0174533) is still around 1k htz. am I doing that wrong?

Comment: empirically discovered the answer is sin(f * ticks / 122.5)